# Good-Turing smoothing implementation problems

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, nltk, smoothing

I want to implement the Good-Turing smoothing method which will improve my language model.

Let's start with the theory (for simplicity, consider the unigram model).

There is a corpus (e.g. a literary work or any huge text). Through it we are building a language model. After we built it, we can find the probability of occurrence of the word. I have created this model using MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimation) with a high value of perplexity (the value of the quality of the constructed model, a high value is bad).

I found a way to improve it with using Good-Turing smoothing:

[image: Good-Turing smoothing]

[image: Good-Turing smoothing 2]

Here:

```
P - the probability of use of the word
c - the number of use of the word
N_c - the count words with a frequency - c
N - the count words in the corpus
```

My code on Python 3:

```
def good_turing(tokens):
    N = len(tokens) + 1    
    C = Counter(tokens)    
    N_c = Counter(list(C.values()))
    assert(N == sum([k * v for k, v in N_c.items()]))
    default_value = N_c[1] / N
    model = defaultdict(lambda: default_value)
    types = C.keys()
    B = len(types)  
    for _type in types:
        c = C[_type]
        model[_type] = (c + 1) * N_c[c + 1] / (N_c[c] * N) # Exception - "math domain error"
    return model
```

There are problems here:

- **word with a frequency c + 1 can not be in the corpus**, so we try to
  take log(0) and get Math Domain Error
- how to calculate **the probability of the most used word** after smoothing?

After reading a few articles my study of this subject came to the construction of the following formulas:

[image: estimate]

So the main question is: **how to get this *E* function**?
I found this:

[image: log]

but I don't know how to search *a* and *b* coefficients in scipy or etc.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For the problem with frequencies that do not occur, look in your textbook (or elsewhere) for work-arounds. It's a standard problem for Good-Turing smoothing. E.g., look at the Z_r function in the [wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation#The_method)